# Appending a stream of repeated bytes to IO in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I am writing a program that requires writing a large amount of repeated bytes to a file in Python.

In order to simplify the question, I will be using representations of the data.
`buffer` is always the returned result of `open(file_name, "a+")` and `b"0"` will an arbitrary representation of the "repeated data"

Suppose I want to write the repeated data 50,000 times, there are 3 ways of doing this I've thought of thus far.

The first way is to generate the data in memory first, then write it (which uses a lot of memory)

```py
data = b"0" * 50_000
buffer.write(data)
```

The second way is to write each iteration in a loop (which is extremely slow)

```py
for _ in range(50_000):
    buffer.write(b"0")
```

Lastly the third way is to combine the two, and write bigger segments (which is a lot faster than the second option, but slower than the first, and on top of that, it uses memory even when it's in use, plus overall this design is extremely ugly)

```py
data_x1 = b"0"
data_x10 = b"0" * 10
data_x100 = b"0" * 100
data_x1000 = b"0" * 1000

# writing in a loop using bigger to smaller segments
# until there is no more to write
num_left = 50_000
while num_left > 0:
    if num_left >= 1000:
        buffer.write(data_x1000)
        num_left -= 1000
    elif num_left >= 100:
        buffer.write(data_x100)
        num_left -= 100
    elif num_left >= 10:
        buffer.write(data_x10)
        num_left -= 10
    else:
        buffer.write(data_x1)
        num_left -= 1
```

TLDR: the goal is to repeatedly write a specified set of bytes to file without using a Python loop, nor generating the entire sequence in memory first.

I have been looking at `BufferedWriter`'s write method and noticed that it takes a bytes-like object.
If it is possible, the optimal method would be being able to create a "bytes-like" object that simulates a stream of repeated data, that can be written x amount of times by the buffer without using a Python loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have tried to address the above mentioned issue by making the question much more straightforward.

Comment: Your third way is only ugly because you made it ugly. I'd do a combination of the first two ways but much nicer.

Comment: did you manage to find a good soluton here or benchmark any others?

Comment: @ti7 I have opted to use your solution, I don't believe there's an efficient way to implement it otherwise without significant effort to file writing in C, and since it only creates a memory view, it's not a significant updraft with the only downside being preallocated memory. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: anytime / excellent - to help the community and to gain some reputation yourself, please mark it as the Answer with the check to its left! (casually, you may also find there's no benefit to a chunked data size over a few MB, say 10MB, and a faster storage device may make a world of difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the largest block you reasonably can and slice the last write smaller

```py
# largest block you can put into memory
# replicate block until some limit
# must wrap at end if data isn't all the same
data = b"0" * 50_000

added_length = 120_000

with open(file_name, "ab+") as fh:  # bytes mode makes math work
    while fh.tell() < added_length:
        fh.write(data[:added_length - fh.tell()])  # don't write too much
```

Note when opening `"a"`, `.tell()` will start at `0` and is an *offset* from the initial file ending .. however, you may find opening `"r+"` and `.seek()`ing to the end is nicer if you want to read other content in the same go or get the total file size

Comment: Why use `fh.tell()`.  Just use `q, r = divmod(added_length, len(data))`.  You then write `data` `q` times and then a truncatated `r` bytes to finish off.

Comment: ah, they will have the same result and whichever case clarity should really reign here - plausibly writing exactly N times will be more robust, but I'd expect an `IOError` if anything goes seriously awry!

Comment: This looks a lot more elegant, although truncating the bytes creates it as a new object in memory, which in turn makes this use a lot of memory too. The goal of the original implementation's of 3 was to reduce the number of iterations, but also to reduce memory usage.

Comment: slicing should not create a new object, but a _view_

Comment: This is probably the better solution I'm going for then, although it would still be best if I didn't have to have a pre-generated chunk as it's an optional functionality, I'm thinking maybe there's a way to create a lower level module that can continuously write one section of memory into a file without moving the pointer

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to try to write using large buffers, you are probably best going with the system default buffer size.

```
import io
data = b'0' * io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
full, extra = divmod(total_bytes_to_write, io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
with open(file_name, "ab+") as fh:
    for _ in range(full):
        fh.write(data)
    fh.write(data[:extra]
```

You could possibly gain a little bit by using a multiple of the default buffer size, but be sure to also use this value in the `open` command.

```
import io
buffer_size = 4 * io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
data = b'0' * buffer_size
full, extra = divmod(total_bytes_to_write, buffer+size)
with open(file_name, "ab+", buffering=buffer_size) as fh:
    .. same as above ...
```

User @trapdrap (see comments) claims that in all cases you should use `buffering = 0` in all cases since you don't want or need buffering.

Comment: Using the `buffering` param keeps the objects in memory to dump all at once, which is also a huge memory issue. Writing 75mb without buffering uses 400kb of memory, while using buffering at 75mb uses 80mb of memory, and this is repeated across all instances writing at the same time

Comment: @trapdrap. So you think it should just be `buffering = 0` in all cases?  Added a comment to that effect.